# add html page on another html like ads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

if I select more than 5 I want that another Html page will pop up like an ads to the user will unselect one of the 5 selected

```
let counter = 0;
    $('.switched').change(function () {

        if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('clicked')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('notClicked');
            counter--;
            console.log(counter);
        }
        else if (counter == 5) {
            $("#htmlTemplate").empty();
            $("#htmlTemplate").load("popUp.html");
            $(".selectedCoins").append(".clicked");
        }
        else if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('notClicked')) {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('notClicked');
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass('clicked');
                counter++;
                console.log(counter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I posted an answer from what I understood but I'm not sure it answers what you're looking for, don't hesitate to add details or explanations so I will see if I have to change or delete my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add it through bootstrap modal for example given at this link,

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

and you can customize it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your need but you don't necessarily need to go to another page to load an ad, especially if you want to interact with the previous one.

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelectorAll(".select").forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", () => {
    e.classList.toggle("selected");
    if(e.classList.contains("selected")){
      counter ++;
    }else{
      counter --;
    }
    if(counter == 5){
      document.getElementById("ad").classList.remove("d-none")
    }else{
      document.getElementById("ad").classList.add("d-none")
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.select{
  display:inline-block;
}
.select, #ad{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#ad{
  background-color:blue;
}
.selected{
  background-color:orange;
}
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select"></div>
<div class="select"></div>
<div class="select"></div>
<div class="select"></div>
<div class="select"></div>
<div id="ad" class="d-none"></div>
```